# Reclaim (free space) on MacOS after deleting disk partition

Tags: mac

This is what shows when I put `diskutil list` in Terminal:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE        IDENTIFIER
0:  GUID_partition_scheme                           *1.0 TB     disk0
1:  Apple_APFS_ISC          Container disk2         524.3 MB    disk0s1
2:  Apple_APFS              Container disk4         800.0 GB    disk0s2
3:  Apple_APFS              Container disk1         2.5 GB      disk0s3
    (free space)                                    192.2 GB    –
4:  Apple_APFS_Recovery     Container disk3         5.4 GB      5.4 GB

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
#:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE        IDENTIFIER
0:  APFS Container Scheme   —                       +2.5 GB     disk1
                            Physical Store disk0s3
1:  APFS Volume             Preboot                 62.7 MB     disk1s3
2:  APFS Volume             Recovery                20.5 KB     disk1s4

/dev/disk4 (synthesized):
#:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE        IDENTIFIER
0:  APFS Container Scheme   —                       +800.0 GB   disk4
                            Physical Store disk0s2
1:  APFS Volume             Macintosh HD            9.2 GB      disk4s1
2:  APFS Snapshot           com.apple.os.update—    9.2 GB      disk4s1s1
3:  APFS Volume             Preboot                 5.2 GB      disk4s2
4:  APFS Volume             Recovery                862.6 MB    disk4s3
5:  APFS Volume             Data                    323.5 GB    disk4s5
6:  APFS Volume             VM                      20.5 KB     disk4s6
```

How do I reclaim the free space and add it to my main partition?

###### Picture:

[image: Output from diskutil list command]

Comment: Please don't add text in a picture. Instead, copy it and then put it in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

##### You should be able to do this with the Disk Utility GUI

The following should work if your `diskutil list` shows `(free space)` for your `disk0`:

1. Open Disk Utility (GUI), e.g. via Spotlight Search.
2. Click "View" and select "Show all devices".
3. On the left, click on your disk drive at the root of the navigation tree.
4. In the upper right, click "Partition".
5. In the opening prompt, click the grey "Partition" button.
   The partitioning GUI will open and show a big circle with different partitions.
   Dashed parts are used, while solid parts are "free to use".
6. Select the white "Free space" area.
7. Click the "–" at the bottom of the circle.
   This integrates the free space into one of your partitions.
8. Drag around the partition borders to change their individual space as you see fit.
   (If e.g. the "Free space" wasn't integrated into your main partition right away.)
9. Click "Apply", confirm "Partition", and wait for the process to finish.

##### If `diskutil list` doesn't show `(free space)` for `disk0`

This is in my experience most common if you resize virtual disks of Mac VMs. You will most likely get an error: `The new size must be different from the existing size`.
To remedy this, do the following:

1. Open/Stay in Terminal
2. Run `diskutil repair disk0`
3. Do the above steps in the GUI, or:
   Run `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1 0`.

###### Disclaimer:

This second part I adapted from [this AskDiffernt answer by Ilya K](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/390791).